# confusing if else with php variable

Tags: php, if-statement

what is the reason for this;

if i go into my settings page and enable this

```
 <? if ( $setts['user_lang']) { ?>
                     <td nowrap style="border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <?=$languages_list;?>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                     <? } ?>
```

works

if i do this

```
<? if (1==1) { ?>
                     <td nowrap style="border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <?=$languages_list;?>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                     <? } ?>
```

it only displays the border-left bit; what can cause this if else loop to not display the variable?

Comment: Shouldn't `if (if (` be just `if(`

Comment: Just a clarification - the `if...then` syntax is not a `loop`.  It is a `conditional expression`

Answer (score 1):

I would say that when `$setts['user_lang']` evaluates to false, the variable `$languages_list` has not been set.  So it IS displaying the variable, but the variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do is check the existence of the `$setts['user_lang']` element. In this case you should use the [isset() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  to check the existence of your `$setts['user_lang']` element.

`<?php if (isset($setts['user_lang'])) { /* do work here */ } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Your $languages_list might be empty?

This works

```
<?
$languages_list = 'blabla';
if (1==1) { 
?>
    <td nowrap style="border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;" align="center">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?=$languages_list;?>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: when you see the border it actually means that the for loop worked as intended.